# OOLua compile errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, oolua

### Code

```
#include <OOLua/oolua.h>
class foo
{
public:
  int bar();
};

OOLUA_CLASS_NO_BASES(foo)//class has no bases
    OOLUA_NO_TYPEDEFS
    OOLUA_MEM_FUN_0(int,bar)
OOLUA_CLASS_END
```

### Compiler output

```
main.cpp(21) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'bar'
main.cpp(22) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
main.cpp(22) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
main.cpp(22) : warning C4183: 'OOLUA_MEM_FUN_0': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
```

### Using

Visual Studio 2008
OOLua 1.2.1

(OOLua .lib has been built and linked to)

### Links

http://code.google.com/p/oolua/

### Question

How can it be fixed? The code segment is from the 'Cheat Sheet' of OOLua's google code website.

### Solved -> but still has problems

[OOLua link errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014746/oolua-link-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry you are having problems with the library, there is a mailing list set up for problems such as you are seeing http://groups.google.com/group/oolua-user?pli=1

The problem is due to a typo in the cheat sheet where "OOLUA_MEM_FUN_0" should read "OOLUA_MEM_FUNC_0". Thank you for drawing attention to the matter I will correct this.
Liam

Answer (score 0):

It is only by chance that I have seen your message here, I would encourage you to use the forms of communication which I have detailed to you. I will not only be able to help you yet also anybody else who has similar problems.
As with any link errors for any library please post an example which displays the errors and the error messages in their entirety, as I will be more equipped to help you.
Thank you
Liam

Comment: I always try to solve the problem on my own first. As for not posting the link error .... Stackoverflow follows the format of question and answer, and in this case the question was answered ( and I posted right after I had a chance to compile :P ).