# OOLua link errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, oolua

### Code

```
#include <OOLua/oolua.h>

class foo
{
public:
  int bar();
};

OOLUA_CLASS_NO_BASES(foo)//class has no bases
    OOLUA_NO_TYPEDEFS
    OOLUA_MEM_FUNC_0(int,bar)
OOLUA_CLASS_END

void test()
{
    OOLUA::Script s;
    s.register_class<foo>();
}
```

### Compiler output

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct OOLUA::Proxy_class<class foo>::Reg_type_const * OOLUA::Proxy_class<class foo>::class_methods_const" (?class_methods_const@?$Proxy_class@Vfoo@@@OOLUA@@2PAUReg_type_const@12@A)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct OOLUA::Proxy_class<class foo>::Reg_type * OOLUA::Proxy_class<class foo>::class_methods" (?class_methods@?$Proxy_class@Vfoo@@@OOLUA@@2PAUReg_type@12@A)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static char const * const OOLUA::Proxy_class<class foo>::class_name" (?class_name@?$Proxy_class@Vfoo@@@OOLUA@@2QBDB)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static char const * const OOLUA::Proxy_class<class foo>::class_name_const" (?class_name_const@?$Proxy_class@Vfoo@@@OOLUA@@2QBDB)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int const OOLUA::Proxy_class<class foo>::name_size" (?name_size@?$Proxy_class@Vfoo@@@OOLUA@@2HB)
```

### Using

Visual Studio 2008

OOLua 1.2.1

```
(OOLua .lib has been built and linked to)
(OOLua solution via premake 3 with test.unit and profile projects removed)
(OOLua obtained via SVN -> trunk | Jan 3rd)
```

### Links

http://code.google.com/p/oolua/

[OOLua compile errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009434/oolua-compile-errors)

### Question

How can it be fixed?

### Solution

```
class foo
{
public:
  int bar()
  {
      return 0;
  }
};

OOLUA_CLASS_NO_BASES(foo)//class has no bases
    OOLUA_NO_TYPEDEFS
    OOLUA_MEM_FUNC_0(int,bar)
OOLUA_CLASS_END

EXPORT_OOLUA_FUNCTIONS_1_NON_CONST(foo /*name of class*/
                                  ,bar)/*function being exposed*/
EXPORT_OOLUA_FUNCTIONS_0_CONST(foo)

void test()
{
    OOLUA::Script s;
    s.register_class<foo>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/oolua/wiki/CheatSheet#Has_a_member_function_which_takes_no_parameters

> Then in a source file expose the class
>   telling the framework that the
>   instance has a function of interest
>   yet no constant member functions, also
>   providing the name it will be
>   identified by in Lua code(foo).

```
EXPORT_OOLUA_FUNCTIONS_1_NON_CONST(foo /*name of class*/
                                  ,bar)/*function being exposed*/
EXPORT_OOLUA_FUNCTIONS_0_CONST(foo)
```